# Apache “rotatelogs” not working for given file size

Tags: windows, xampp

According to Apache documentation for `rotatelogs`, I have implemented the log file format as follows in httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
    CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access_log-%Y.log 10M" common
<IfModule log_config_module>
```

It created a file `access_log.log-2015` and recording the logs but it is not rotating file after it reaches 10MB, and the file size is now 20MB.

Is there anything I'm missing here? I am on XAMPP on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotatelogs documentation says that the log file template should be specific enough to give a new name whenever the size limit is reached. Yours isn't. Try changing to include month and day.

Doc implies that when limit is reached file will be truncated and reopened. That's not what you're seeing but could be down to platform differences.

Answer (score 1):

Your setting is this:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
    CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access_log-%Y.log 10M" common
<IfModule log_config_module>
```

So the way this is setup, `access_log.log-2015` will definitely rotate on January 1, 2016 to `access_log.log-2015` irregardless of the size setting. If you want daily rotation, you need to set something more than year such as month and day like this:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
    CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access_log-%Y-%m-%d.log 10M" common
<IfModule log_config_module>
```

Or even do hours, minutes and seconds in addition to month and day:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
    CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access_log-%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S.log 10M" common
<IfModule log_config_module>
```

The idea is simple: If the logfile reaches 10MB in size and the filename is just a year, then that one year naming scheme will be retained for each “rotation.” You are not seeing the rotation since it is just appending it to `access_log-2015.log`.

By adding more specificity you are assured that the logs will not only rotate when the 10MB cutoff is reached, but you have a pseudo-timestamp in the filename as well to know exactly when the rotation happens.